How to to move an existing user created in snowflake_user resource to snowflake_legacy_service_user resource?
I've have upgraded to Snowflake provider version 0.97. What is the best approach to move existing users created in snowflake_user resource to snowflake_legacy_service_user resource.
I've tried:-

Replace the resource name from snowflake_user to snowflake_legacy_service_user. Use import command, I tried to import an existing user into snowflake_legacy_service_user resource. This didn't work because the existing user was destroyed and a new user was created.

Use moved command, I tried to move the user from snowflake_user resource to snowflake_legacy_service_user resource. This didn't work because, I get the error message below


Error: Move Resource State Not Supported
│ The "snowflake_legacy_service_user" resource type does not support moving
│ resource state across resource types.

Maybe this is the same thing you already tried, but just sharing it if not, since it looks related: https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/terraform-provider-snowflake/blob/main/docs/technical-documentation/resource_migration.md#resource-migration
